# Container with inner borders only

Tags: html, css

How can I create a container that has INNER borders / padding ONLY. For example it should output the following:

[image]

Sample markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
         <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { width: 960px; }
.item { float: left; width: 300px; height: 100px; }
```

(in the above, `.item` would be output 9 times).

**This needs to be IE8+ compatible and done using the most efficient method.**

Comment: I wonder how you would expect to evaluate efficiency. It will only be the most efficient method until something else comes along.  5 minute abs... 4 minute abs.

Comment: The markup you've provided your basically just asking us to do it for you. Perhpas you can make a fiddle, or give it an honest go and come back with any problems you encounter

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the output you could give the elements classes

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item item-1">
         <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
         <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
         <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and then use

```
.item { width: 300px; height: 100px; float: left;}
.item-2 { margin: 0 20px; }
.items-secondrow { margin: 20px }
.items-secondrow-block-2 { margin: 20px 20px; }
```

if you do not have control (and easier, but not supported in older versions of IE)

```
.item:nth-child(1) { //code }
.item:nth-child(2) { //code }
//etc ..
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="itemList">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container { width: 960px; }
.itemList { margin-left: -30px; margin-bottom: -30px;}
.item { float: left; width:298px; border: 1px solid #000; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom:30px; }
```